# How to type "nicely" the following math expression using libertinust1math math font

Tags: fonts, mathtools, math-fonts

Using the following packages, i.e. libertinust1math in particular, how can I type nicely subscripts of \mathbf expressions?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[ISO, upint]{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,bb=boondox]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[final,babel=true]{microtype}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    p(\boldsymbol{\mathbf{x}}_k\mid\boldsymbol{\mathbf{y}}_{0:k})
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For instance, here the "y" is taking more vertical space and its subscript is lower as well compared to the other "x" expression. The standard fences () look nice on the "x" but not on the "y". Should I just don't care as it is "typographically" good as a result and I should just use \big fences or should I tweak the fonts?

EDIT: the cause was using \boldsymbol{\mathbf{}} to implement the bold math expression, causing the weird spacing as in the image.
[image]

File list (date/version):
https://justpaste.it/6dequ

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test. We cannot do much with just a preamble. Additionally, please exclude any irrelevant packages from the example.

Comment: Is it supposed to denote a conditional probability?

Comment: @Bernard yes, it does denote a conditional probability

Comment: @daleif added minimal example, the left packages I am not sure are all needed or have some effects on the final result, that is the reason I left them.

Comment: Can you show show package versions you're using. For me via `pdflatex` both subscripts sits on the same line

Comment: @daleif I used the command "miktex packages list --template "{isInstalled}, {displayName}, {version}" | grep ^true >isInstalledVersion.txt" to list the installed packages and related versions, here there is a snapshot:
 https://justpaste.it/9123m

Comment: That shows all package of your installation, no way I'm doing through that. Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, then recompile your example above. Then the versions are listed in the log file. You can add that to your question. `\listfiels` lists versions **and** date, which is a lot easier to handle

Comment: @daleif I'm sorry I tried to filter them but I am not used to detail with packages management, I used your solution and edited the question with the result (I gave you another snapshot as the weird indention of the log file messed with the tex StackExchange code editor). Thanks

Comment: @daleif found the cause, in the original code I used some old macro that used "\boldsymbol{\mathbf{}}}" instead of just "\mathbf{}", should I just remove them?

Comment: I normally just use thye `bm` package and its `\bm{...}` command, no `\boldsymbol` or `\mathbf` (gives you italic `x` which I prefer)

Comment: @Luca Your code doesn't produce the output in the image, so the problem lies elsewhere (and it seems you found the cause). Anyway, you load `cmap` that does nothing, given your font setup; `amssymb` is not necessary, because `libertinust1math` already takes care of that; loading `mathalpha` with the `scr` option and then loading also `eucal` is contradictory.

Comment: @daleif the specifically used fonts do implement the macros \mathbf \mathit and \mathbfit though if I am not mistaken. What do you think about using an external solution like \bm vs doing it "natively" in my specific situation?

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for the insights, I am writing the document very slowly and learning new things meanwhile, some code is old and as you suggested should be substituted. I am trying to learn fonts using pdflatex these days but it's a mess for a user like me.
1) I thought cmap for used in order to have an utf8 output pdf, e.g. copy-pastestable output or parseable.
2) amssymb: thanks, I will read its documentation and remove it, just for the sake of learning.
3) yes, while writing the question, I noticed that too. Thanks!

Comment: @Luca mainly: I find it confusing that `\mathbf{x}` leaves an **upright** `x` not a bold version of the normal `x`. Plus it's less typing.

Comment: With MWE, which you provide now, I can't reproduce showed result. Result is as expected. Subscripts are aligned.